# Función aguinaldo

Tags: javascript

Es mi primera experiencia en el sitio. Tenía que hacer una función con las siguientes indicaciones:

```
// definir una función que retorne cual fue el aguinaldo de un trabajador en el año.
// la misma recibe por parametro un array de objetos con los meses del año y el salario recibido en cada mes.
// debe buscar cual fue el salario mas alto del primer semestre y el mas alto del segundo semestre.
// tiene que retornar el aguinaldo total sumando el salario mas alto del primer semestre y el mas alto del segundo semestre.
```

Lo que yo logré hacer es esto:

```js
function aguinaldo(salarios) {
    let salarioPrimerSemestre = 0;
    let salarioSegundoSemestre = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < salarios.length; i++) {
        if (salarios[i].mes === "enero" || salarios[i].mes === "febrero" || salarios[i].mes === "marzo" || 
            salarios[i].mes === "abril" || salarios[i].mes === "mayo" || salarios[i].mes === "junio" ) {
                
            salarioPrimerSemestre = Math.max(salarioPrimerSemestre, salarios[i].salario);
        }
        if (salarios[i].mes === "julio" || salarios[i].mes === "agosto" || salarios[i].mes === "septiembre" || 
            salarios[i].mes === "octubre" || salarios[i].mes === "noviembre" || salarios[i].mes === "diciembre") {
            salarioSegundoSemestre = Math.max(salarioSegundoSemestre, salarios[i].salario);
        }
    }
    return salarioPrimerSemestre + salarioSegundoSemestre;
}

let salarios = [
        {mes: "enero", salario: 20000},
        {mes: "febrero", salario: 2000},
        {mes: "marzo", salario: 3000},
        {mes: "abril", salario: 2000},
        {mes: "mayo", salario: 50000},
        {mes: "junio", salario: 3000},
        {mes: "julio", salario: 4000},
        {mes: "agosto", salario: 3000},
        {mes: "septiembre", salario: 60000},
        {mes: "octubre", salario: 10000},
        {mes: "noviembre", salario: 7000},
        {mes: "diciembre", salario: 9000},
    ];

console.log(aguinaldo(salarios));
```

Pero seguramente se puede lograr hacer en muchas menos líneas. Me gustaría ver alguna opción de como hacerlo ya que estuve probando y no he logrado nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo crearía 2 arrays, en donde cada array tendrá elementos que representen a los meses del primer y segundo semestre.

```
let primerSemestre = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio"];
let segundoSemestre = ["julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"];
```

Luego podemos hacer un [**`filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) al array de objetos `salarios` para encontrar los elementos de `salarios` en el que el valor de su atributo `mes` se encuentren en el primer y segundo array, esto lo hacemos con [**`includes()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
let salarioPrimerSemestre = salarios.filter(e => primerSemestre.includes(e.mes))
let salarioSegundoSemestre = salarios.filter(e => segundoSemestre.includes(e.mes))
```

Es decir, le indico que me filtre todos los elementos del array de objetos `salarios` en donde el valor de su atributo `mes` de esos elementos se encuentren en el array `primerSemestre` y `segundoSemestre`, ambos almacenados en distintas variables.

*Recuerda que `salarios` es un **array de objetos**, en donde sus elementos de ese array son **objetos**, y esos objetos tiene **2 atributos**, que son **`mes`** y **`salario`**.*

---

Entonces, necesitamos ingresar al valor del atributo `salario` de los elementos para obtener los salarios de cada uno de ellos, esto lo podemos hacer con [**`map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), quedando el código así:

```
let salarioPrimerSemestre = salarios.filter(e => primerSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario)
let salarioSegundoSemestre = salarios.filter(e => segundoSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario)
```

Y de los salarios obtenidos, capturamos el máximo con `Math.max()` (se usa `...` para **desestructurar** el array que nos devuelve `map()`, ya que `Math.max()` espera una lista de argumentos **en lugar de un array**), quedando el código así:

```
let salarioPrimerSemestre = Math.max(...salarios.filter(e => primerSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario));
let salarioSegundoSemestre = Math.max(...salarios.filter(e => segundoSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario));
```

Y por último retornamos la suma de ambos:

```
return salarioPrimerSemestre + salarioSegundoSemestre;
```

---

**Código final:**

```js
function aguinaldo(salarios) {
  let primerSemestre = ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio"];
  let segundoSemestre = ["julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"];

  let salarioPrimerSemestre = Math.max(...salarios.filter(e => primerSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario));
  let salarioSegundoSemestre = Math.max(...salarios.filter(e => segundoSemestre.includes(e.mes)).map(e => e.salario));

  return salarioPrimerSemestre + salarioSegundoSemestre;
}

let salarios = [
  { mes: "enero", salario: 20000 },
  { mes: "febrero", salario: 2000 },
  { mes: "marzo", salario: 3000 },
  { mes: "abril", salario: 2000 },
  { mes: "mayo", salario: 50000 },
  { mes: "junio", salario: 3000 },
  { mes: "julio", salario: 4000 },
  { mes: "agosto", salario: 3000 },
  { mes: "septiembre", salario: 60000 },
  { mes: "octubre", salario: 10000 },
  { mes: "noviembre", salario: 7000 },
  { mes: "diciembre", salario: 9000 },
];

console.log(aguinaldo(salarios));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Cris. Esta muy bien desarrollada y explicada. Saludos.

Comment: @PabloScherpa me alegro, recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándole al ✔️ (que se encuentra al lado izquierdo de mi respuesta) y darle voto arriba para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.